# Password for user is not asked anymore

Tags: debian, sudo, authentication, lightdm

I am using Debian Stretch with lightdm. Suddenly, I am no longer asked for a password when I log in. As soon as I fill in my username and press tab, the password field is removed and I can log in without ever entering it.

Moreover:

- With a command line login, the situation is the same: I only have to enter my username to log in.
- No password is asked when I use sudo, even across reboots and after
  executing `sudo -K`.
- Some applications, such as the root terminal in Thunar, warn me that due to my 'authentication mechanism setup', I do not need to enter a password.
- My password is no longer accepted by programs which have a graphic prompt for a password, such as `synaptic-pkexec`. `sudo synaptic-pkexec` does work.

The answers I'm finding are specific to settings in lightdm, or in `/etc/sudoers`. However those files look normal, and this problem seems to be more general. Can anyone offer pointers on how to find out what has changed in my system?

Comment: What did you change?  Password authentication _does not_ disable itself for no reason.

Comment: Any messages from `pam*` in the journal? Check with `sudo journalctl -b` to see messages for current boot session.

Comment: I don't remember changing anything, this is why I was puzzled.

The journal reports however:
lightdm[1193]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user

Apparently I have no password set anymore, then. I don't know how this happened. Setting a new password solved everything. Thanks for your help, I'll submit my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause was that there was no password set anymore for my user. I executed:

`sudo journalctl -b | grep pam`

And noticed:

`lightdm[1193]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user`

The problem was then solved by executing `passwd` at the terminal and setting a new password.